# Symfony2 & Phpunit why \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase works but PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase does not?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have a small Symfony2 project in order to try something and I wrote the following test class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Managers\CRUD;

// use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class PersonManagerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function testTrue()
  {
    print "Test True";
    $this->assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

That works as supposed to but if I try to refactor like that:

```
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Managers\CRUD;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class PersonManagerTest extends TestCase
{
  public function testTrue()
  {
    print "Test True";
    $this->assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'TestCase' not found in /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/apps/sjonapi/src/AppBundle/Tests/Managers/CRUD/PersonManagerTest.php on line 8

And I wonder why does it happen?

My composer.json is:

```
{
    "name" : "pcmagas/sjonapi",
    "license" : "WFPL",
    "type" : "project",
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "" : "src/"
        },
        "classmap" : [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
  "repositories": [{
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/non-web/pcmagas-libs"
  }],
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony" : "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm" : "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "~1.4",
        "doctrine/common": "~2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0",
        "nilportugues/jsonapi-bundle" : "^1.5",
        "pcmagas/libs": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.3"
    },
    "require-dev" : {
        "sensio/generator-bundle" : "~3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge" : "~2.7",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "5.5.*"
    },
    "scripts" : {
        "post-install-cmd" : [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd" : [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config" : {
        "bin-dir" : "bin"
    },
    "extra" : {
        "symfony-app-dir" : "app",
        "symfony-web-dir" : "web",
        "symfony-assets-install" : "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters" : {
            "file" : "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "map": [
                    [
                        "*",
                        "CommonLibs\\Helpers",
                        "CommonLibs\\Interfaces"
                    ]
              ]
    },
    "description" : "A simple Demo using JSON API"
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure PHPUnit did not adopt name spaces until 6.x.

Comment: `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` was added as a forward-compatibility alias in 5.4.3 (in 5.4.0 it had been originally put in as `phpunit\framework\TestCase`).